# Proving linear independance of this particular set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ let say, $\lbrace v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n} \rbrace$ such the generated of this vectors is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, prove that the set $\lbrace v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n} \rbrace$ is linear independant.

I try it by contradiction, let say $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ are linear dependant then for a linear combination $\lambda_{1} v_{1}+....+\lambda_{n} v_{n}=0$ we have at least one $\lambda_{i} \neq 0$ for one $i \in  \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$. Then $\lambda_{i}v_{i}=0$ as $v_{i} \neq 0$ we have that $\lambda_{i}=0$ proving that the given set of vectors is linear independant. Somehow I feel my proof is sort of incomplete, as what if two $\lambda_{i}$ scalars or more are not zero? Can anyone help me ending the proof? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda_i \neq 0$, you can express

$$v_i = -\frac{1}{\lambda_i}\sum_{j \neq i} \lambda_j v_j$$

Hence $v_i \in \operatorname{Span}\left( \{v_1,\ldots, v_n \} \setminus \{ v_i\}\right)$

Now, we can examine the dimension of $\operatorname{Span}\{ v_1,\ldots, v_n \}$ and compare it with dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on what previous results you are allowed to use.  I shall assume that you have already learned and are allowed to use the following:

> If $S$ is a spanning set for a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and $T$ is a linearly independent set in $V$, then $|S|\ge|T|$.

Then you can argue as follows: if $\{{\bf v}_1,\ldots,{\bf v}_n\}$ is linearly dependent then there is a vector in this set which is a linear combination of the others; this vector can be removed to give a set $S$ with the same span, namely, $\Bbb R^n$.  But $|S|=n-1$; and
$$T=\{{\bf e}_1,\ldots,{\bf e}_n\}$$
is an independent set in $\Bbb R^n$ with $|T|=n$; this contradicts the above result.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Is there any link you have in order to check the lemma you wrote! @David

Comment: Don't know but you should find it in any first course on linear algebra.